# php - unable to load & use Imagick (DLL errors) (Windows 8)

Tags: php, dll, windows-8, dependencies, imagick

I have downloaded and installed Imagick, added it to the system path and successfully tested the installation.

Also, I've downloaded the php_imagick.dll and put it in my php/ext/ folder.
Finally, I added this `extension=php_imagick.dll` in the php.ini file.

(Following [this](http://www.elxsy.com/2009/07/installing-imagemagick-on-windows-and-using-with-php-imagick/) tutorial)

Running php via localhost gives me the following error (php does not crash):

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\ ...

When inspecting dependencies of php_imagick.dll with a program called 'Dependency Walker', I see the [this](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=259e8o5&s=5).

Tried to fix it (without success) by :

- using different versions of Imagick installation
- using older php_imagick.dll versions
- multiple reboots of the system
- relocating dependent dll's (this causes a dependency 'cannot find' chain reaction)

So, I think I'm supposed to look for a dependency location fix, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for this: `http://valokuva.org/`
There you will find steps on how to install imagick on windows.

Comment: Thx, I followed the post on November 30, 2012 with success. (made sure all binaries were compiled with VC9)

Comment: The link is not longer available... FYI. May 22, 2015